# Create Magento payment method module with custom form

Tags: template, blocks, payment-methods

I'm relatively new to Magento, and I'm having a little difficulty with creating a payment method module with a custom form (based on my needs). I've already followed two or three tutorials (one of them on the official Magento website), but none of them covered the front-end part of the module. [This tutorial](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/payment/create-payment-method-module) for example, shows how to create a payment method module which derives from the `paygate` module, and it has its own form.
 OK, I understand that perhaps that is not the intention of those tutorials, but as I'm new to Magento development I'll need that kind of guide I guess.
By my understanding, it has to do with blocks and templates, but that's as far as I've gone. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/payment/create-payment-method-module

refer this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a protected class variable in your payment method class:

```
protected $_formBlockType = 'mymodule/form';
```

resulting in form template `app/design/frontend/*/*/template/mymodule/form.phtml`.